# LicFileLicenseProvider class and licenses.licx file

Tags: c#

I am going to create a `LicFileLicenseProvider` based license provider. I have read many articles, questions and answers regarding this content. Finally, I have created my license provider, `MyLicFileLicenseProvider` and it has two modes, RunTime and DesignTime. I am going to set license for design time only. I did it and it is working good as well. Therefore, the license will be (and should be) used only during the compiling with existance of the "licenses.licx" file.

A. Normal Case

1) Create a class:

```
[LicenseProvider(typeof(MyLicFileLicenseProvider))]

public class XXXObject

{

        private License license = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an instance of the XXXObject object.
        /// </summary>
        public XXXObject()
        {
            try
            {
                license = LicenseManager.Validate(typeof(XXXObject), this);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new SecurityException("Invalid license!");
            }               
        }
}
```

2) Then, create a licenses.licx file, content
   Object Full Name, Name space, Version, Culture, PublicKeyToken

3) Create a license file, XXX.XXXObject.lic file.

Now, I have created all necessary stuffs and compiled the project. It is compiled and working well.

B. Bi-normal case.
My question is, as I mentioned in above I have decorated the XXXObject class with the attribute `[LicenseProvider(typeof(MyLicFileLicenseProvider))]`. 
Then, I exclude the licenses.licx file from the project. Then, compiled the project. However, it is still compiling. This is not make sense, because I decorated
the class with [LicenseProvider(typeof(MyLicFileLicenseProvider))], and it should be looking for the licenses.licx, but it did not and compiled without error?

Comment: It doesn't stop compilation.  Your class isn't suitable for a design-time check, it is not a control.  It it were one, you'll override OnHandleCreated() and validate the license if the DesignMode property is true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This means we can't use this licensing mechanism to a library without control or component. My mean is pure class libraries. Am I correct?

Comment: (If you override OnHandleCreated without sealing it, all it would take to circumvent the license is a subclass.)